# Can I config \defbibentryset to be robust to non-exist key?

Tags: biblatex

I have two lists of bibliographies. And I use a `refsection` for one

```
\begin{refsection}
              \defbibentryset{test}{not-exist-key}
              \printbibliography[heading=none,....]
\end{refsection}
```

and a normal `printbibliography` for the other

```
\printbibliography
```

It works as expected, until I have just one non-exist key for `\defbibentryset`.
The pdf file can be generated ignoring biber warning, but the other list of bibliography is not in the document, and the citation style is also wrong.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
  \defbibentryset{test}{sugfrudssun}
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}
\textcite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code a [complete but minimal document](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), if possible one that compiles

Comment: `biber` generates an error if no keys in the entry set exist. I don't think things are easily fixed on the LaTeX side. And I'm not sure if this really counts as a `biber` bug…

Comment: @siracusa I just added a MWE.

Comment: Yes, Biber does not deal with this situation particularly gracefully. There is not a lot we can do against that, though. If you are bothered by this I suggest you open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues.

Comment: It bothered me enough, so I opened https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/241 about this.

Comment: @moewe I am looking forward to the next version.

Comment: @jiewuza Well, it might be some time. Don't hold your breath ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out if you are stubborn enough, you can do this…

First I create a `dummy` bibliography entry with `options={dataonly}`. Then I redefine `\defbibentryset` to always include this entry. It won't appear in the bibliography if only non-existing entries are included in the set because of the `skipbib,skiplab` options. Then I slightly adjust `\blx@entryset@i` to do nothing if the current `entrykey` is `dummy`.

If you cite the entry set it will still appear as [].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{dummy,
  options = {dataonly}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\let\origdefbibentryset\defbibentryset
\renewcommand{\defbibentryset}[2]{%
  \origdefbibentryset{#1}{#2,dummy}}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@entryset@i#1{%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@resetdata
     \blx@getdata{#1}%
     \iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{dummy}
       {}
       {\blx@entrysetcount
        \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
        \blx@setoptions@entry
        \addtocounter{instcount}\@ne
        \blx@execute
        \blx@beglangbib
        \blx@begunit
        \blx@anchor
        \blx@entryset@precode
        \blx@driver{\blx@imc@thefield{entrytype}}%
        \blx@entryset@postcode
        \blx@endunit
        \blx@endlangbib}%
     \endgroup}
    {\blx@nounit}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
  \defbibentryset{test}{sugfrudssun}
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}
\textcite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Seems a bit excessive, though. I believe that Biber should bail out slightly more gracefully in this situation: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/241

Comment: @moewe, I didn't say it was a *good* idea ;). Also, as I think about this there are more problems. It still creates an entry with a number. So you will get missing numbers in the bibliography.

Comment: You could add `skiplab` for the number, I think.

Comment: @moewe. Nice, I didn't know about that option.

Comment: Come to think of it `options = {dataonly}` might be the simplest option. Additionally to `skipbib,skiplab` that will also set `skipbiblist` and `uniquename=false , uniquelist=false` (not that the last two should matter).

Comment: @moewe, true! That just leaves citations, which is not as easy as I hoped...

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks for your example. I was thinking `\defbibentryset implies the equivalent of a \nocite command` in biblatex document. So I delete `\textcite{sigfridsson}` from your example and it fails.

Comment: @jiewuza, what output are you expecting if you delete `\textcite{sigfridsson}`? If you do that in my MWE, then no text at all is output and so no PDF is created at all. `\defbibentryset` does imply `\nocite` command, but the set is empty and doesn't exist, so still no output.

Comment: @DavidPurton Well, my understanding about `\defbibentryset implying \nocite` may be wrong. The output I thought before should be the stuff in `\defbibentryset{...}` (in your example, 'sugfrudssun'): if the key exists, it should be the bib item, otherwise, the key itself.

Comment: @jiewuza, no key is printed with `\nocite` whether the key exists or not. And nothing is printed for `\defbibentryset` even if the members of the set exist. No matter what you cite explicitly (single entry or entry set) you will only get a number in brackets [1]. It's the bibliography that contains the data. `\nocite` includes the entry in bibliography without outputting a citation. Similarly `\defbibentryset` includes the set in the bibliography without outputting a citation (provided at least one member of the entry set exists.)

Comment: @jiewuza, To see what I mean, use `\defbibentryset{test}{sigfridsson}` and remove the `\printbibliography`. You'll still get an empty document even though the `test` set now exists.

Comment: @DavidPurton Yes, you are right.